# How to style Bootstrap accordion card only which is active or expanded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 accordion and I want to style `.card` border only for `show collapse`.

```js
var active = document.querySelector(".collapse.show");
active.parentNode.style.border = "1px solid #ea8523";
```

```css
.page-wrapper .default-address {
  padding: 50px 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .page-wrapper .default-address {
    padding: 50px 40px;
  }
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card {
  width: 340px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border: 1px dashed #4e5254;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .card-header {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .default-button {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .default-button img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .default-button span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4e5254;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .default-button .default-name {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 2;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .default-button:not(.collapsed) img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .card-body .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .card-body .form-group label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4e5254;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .card-body .form-group .form-control {
  background-color: #fffbfb;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .card-foot {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .card-foot .btn {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 96px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: #ea8523;
  height: 30px;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .card-foot .btn-primary {
  background-color: #ea8523;
}

.page-wrapper .default-address .card .card-foot .btn-outline-primary {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ea8523;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <section class="default-address">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionAddress">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn default-button collapsed text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <div>
                          <span class="default-name">Raju Sharma</span>
                          <span>64, New Ratna Bunglows, </span>
                          <span>Mumbai, India.</span>
                        </div>
                        <img
                          class="img-fluid"
                          src="./assets/images/icons/arrow-1x.png"
                        />
                      </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionAddress">
              <form>
                <div class="card-body pt-0">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ADDRESS</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ZIP CODE</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CITY</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>COUNTRY</label>
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input">
                      <option>INDIA</option>
                      <option>USA</option>
                      <option>UK</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-foot">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                          CANCEL
                        </button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          SAVE
                        </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn default-button collapsed text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        <div>
                          <span class="default-name">Raju Sharma</span>
                          <span>64, New Ratna Bunglows, </span>
                          <span>Mumbai, India.</span>
                        </div>
                        <img
                          class="img-fluid"
                          src="./assets/images/icons/arrow-1x.png"
                        />
                      </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionAddress">
              <form>
                <div class="card-body pt-0">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ADDRESS</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ZIP CODE</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CITY</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>COUNTRY</label>
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input">
                      <option>INDIA</option>
                      <option>USA</option>
                      <option>UK</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-foot">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                          CANCEL
                        </button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          SAVE
                        </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn default-button collapsed text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        <div>
                          <span class="default-name">Raju Sharma</span>
                          <span>64, New Ratna Bunglows, </span>
                          <span>Mumbai, India.</span>
                        </div>
                        <img
                          class="img-fluid"
                          src="./assets/images/icons/arrow-1x.png"
                        />
                      </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionAddress">
              <form>
                <div class="card-body pt-0">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ADDRESS</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ZIP CODE</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CITY</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>COUNTRY</label>
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input">
                      <option>INDIA</option>
                      <option>USA</option>
                      <option>UK</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-foot">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                          CANCEL
                        </button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          SAVE
                        </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn default-button text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                        <div>
                          <span class="default-name">Raju Sharma</span>
                          <span>64, New Ratna Bunglows, </span>
                          <span>Mumbai, India.</span>
                        </div>
                        <img
                          class="img-fluid"
                          src="./assets/images/icons/arrow-1x.png"
                        />
                      </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordionAddress">
              <form>
                <div class="card-body pt-0">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ADDRESS</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ZIP CODE</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CITY</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>COUNTRY</label>
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input">
                      <option>INDIA</option>
                      <option>USA</option>
                      <option>UK</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-foot">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                          CANCEL
                        </button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          SAVE
                        </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingFive">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn default-button collapsed text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                        <div>
                          <span class="default-name">Raju Sharma</span>
                          <span>64, New Ratna Bunglows, </span>
                          <span>Mumbai, India.</span>
                        </div>
                        <img
                          class="img-fluid"
                          src="./assets/images/icons/arrow-1x.png"
                        />
                      </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordionAddress">
              <form>
                <div class="card-body pt-0">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ADDRESS</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ZIP CODE</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CITY</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>COUNTRY</label>
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input">
                      <option>INDIA</option>
                      <option>USA</option>
                      <option>UK</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-foot">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                          CANCEL
                        </button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          SAVE
                        </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingSix">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn default-button collapsed text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSix">
                        <div>
                          <span class="default-name">Raju Sharma</span>
                          <span>64, New Ratna Bunglows, </span>
                          <span>Mumbai, India.</span>
                        </div>
                        <img
                          class="img-fluid"
                          src="./assets/images/icons/arrow-1x.png"
                        />
                      </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSix" data-parent="#accordionAddress">
              <form>
                <div class="card-body pt-0">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ADDRESS</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ZIP CODE</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CITY</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>COUNTRY</label>
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Default Text Input">
                      <option>INDIA</option>
                      <option>USA</option>
                      <option>UK</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-foot">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                          CANCEL
                        </button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          SAVE
                        </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Now I want orange border `.card` only which is active or expanding and other will have dashed border. I know it can be possible with JavaScript but I am new to JavaScript so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each card will be added to the border when the show class has it. then we select each card with javascript and add click event.

Css:

```
.card.show {
  border: 1px solid orange !important;
}
```

Js:

```
let cards = [...document.querySelectorAll(".card")];
cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener("click", function() {
    cards.forEach(c => c.classList.remove("show"));
    this.classList.add("show")
  })
});
```